# Logging into domain but not able to search it?

Tags: windows-7, domain

For what I've been reading in several similar questions, it seems to me that this is actually a featured designed to work in the way that I'm seeing it, but part of it still does not seem right.

So, I work remotely and I connect through VPN software to my company's network, on which I have access to several shared resources, servers and such. For all of those, I use my domain login and password: mycompany\myuser.

However, when I need to manage resources, (for example, AD groups I own) and I want to add a user to them, the user search functionality from Windows will only allow me to search on my local machine or my local domain. **Is there any workaround on this?**

My solution so far has been bringing up another machine which is joined to the domain (so, I login into it with my domain username and password) and I'm able to manage the resources. Sometimes I may not have the chance to bring up this machine, and I would like to know if there is any workaround on that.

Answer (score 0):

At the worst, you could use "Active Directory Users and Computers":

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

I couldn't seem to find a way to add another domain to the list for the "Search Active Directory" feature.  But you can add whatever domains you want to ADUC.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Got the tools installed and active, but I can't get to manage anything. Should I be a domain admin to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had that problem before. I solved it by adding the Domain Server to my DNS.

1. Go to **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections**
2. Right click on the connection you are using.
3. Click **Properties**.
4. Click **Internet Protocol Version 4** then **Properties**.
5. Add the ip address for the Domain Server as the **Preferred DNS server**. (you may need to restart your computer for the changes to take affect)

   [image: DNS]

Note: You will also want to add your current DNS to the list as well.